# development環境のみで動くソースを記述する方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsには、

- development
- test
- production

と環境がありますが、development環境でのみ動かすソースを記述する方法はありますか？

厳密には、[mileszs/wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)の
`show_as_html: params.key?('debug')`
オプションをdevelopment環境でのみ付与したいと考えております。

Gemfileだと、

```
group :development do
end
```

や

```
group :development, :test do
end
```

といった書き方ができるので、コントローラ内にも記述できるかと思って試したところ、

> undefined method `group' for

となりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元の環境で試した限りでは、コントローラの中であれば

```
if Rails.env == "development"
  #hogehoge
end
```

という書き方ができました。

Comment: どういう検索ワードで調べればよいかわからなかったのですが、`if Rails.env == "development"`で検索をかけれるようになったことで、
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484004/how-can-i-determine-if-my-rails-is-in-the-development-environment-and-not-the-te　を発見することができました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

@cul8erさんの回答
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/20347/9008
により検索ワードが豊富になったので下記のやり方も発見できました。

[testing - How can I determine if my rails is in the development environment and not the test environment? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484004/how-can-i-determine-if-my-rails-is-in-the-development-environment-and-not-the-te)
や
[development environment - How to tell if rails is in production? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967809/how-to-tell-if-rails-is-in-production)
の回答　https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144161/1979953
にある通り環境を示す

`Rails.env.development?`

がありました。

Rails3.1から増えたと本家SOにありますが、そのコメントに
2.3でも動いてるよとあるので、正確にどのバージョンから増えたかは不明。